# PHP - If statements not working

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I'm having some trouble with the following code:

```
$code = $_COOKIE['user'];
$db=mysql_connect ("XXX.XXX.XXX",  "XXX", "XXX") or die ('I cannot connect  to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
$mydb=mysql_select_db("XXX");
$sql="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE UserCode = '$code'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $current = $row['Userpassword'];
};
$toldcurr = $POST["oldpass"];
$pass1 = $_POST["newpass1"];
$pass2 = $_POST["newpass2"];
if ($current !== $toldcurr) {
    header ('Location: changepasserror1.html');
};
if ($pass1 !== $pass2) { 
    header ('Location: changepasserror2.html');
};
$timywhimy = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
$query1 = "UPDATE accounts SET Userpassword='$pass2' WHERE UserCode='$code'";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO accountupdate (`User`, `Change`, `From`, `To`, `Time`) 
VALUES ('$code', 'Password', '$current', '$pass2', '$timywhimy')";
mysql_query($query1);
mysql_query($query2);
header ('Location: changepass.html');
```

The problem i'm having is the

```
if ($current !== $toldcurr) {
        header ('Location: changepasserror1.html');
    };
if ($pass1 !== $pass2) { 
        header ('Location: changepasserror2.html');
    };
```

is not working. When I know that the two variables are not equal, it still continues the script and changes the data in the MySQL database.

Any help is appreciated.

## Update

I've updated my code to

```
 if ($current !== $toldcurr) {
    header ('Location: changepasserror1.html');
    exit();
}
if ($pass1 !== $pass2) { 
    header ('Location: changepasserror2.html');
    exit();
}
```

Apart from that, the only changes are `mysql_` to `mysqli_`.

The problem i'm having is it's always sending me to `changepasserror2.html`, even if `$pass1` and `$pass2` are identical.
Also, it never sends me to `changepasserror1.html`, even when `$current` and `$toldcurr` are different.

What should happen is if `$pass1` = `$pass2` and `$current` = `$toldcurr`, then the database should be updated and the redirect to a success page. If one of those variable does not equal each other, then it will redirect to an error page and no update should happen to the database.

Comment: 1. I would highly recommend you to change your code to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` 2. Add `exit();` after each header call, to make sure the script execution stops 3. The semicolons at the end of the if statements are just useless

Comment: Also, you're open to SQL injections with this code. You shouldn't put data users directly access in your queries.

Comment: @Rizier123 I've added `exit();` after the header calls, and changed the code to `mysqli_` but still the if statements don't work

Comment: @AlexanderWright Good! Now [updated](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28796608/edit) your question (Don't overwrite your old question) add the new code with the changes and tell us if you get any errors, what's not working e.g. What output do you get now and what would you expect

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: @AlexanderWright please up vote my answer or remove correct answer, I don't want any down vote in my profile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first change this `$toldcurr = $POST["oldpass"];` to `$toldcurr = $_POST["oldpass"];`

Answer (score -2):

just use the statement as below it would help

```
  if ($current !== $toldcurr) {
            header ('Location: changepasserror1.html');
            return false;
        }
     if ($pass1 !== $pass2) { 
            header ('Location: changepasserror2.html');
          return false;
        }
```

use above when u do your code in oops style it would be clear and help you out
try to write proper conditional

Comment: Use `exit`, not `return`.

Comment: `return` won't exit script from executing if it's inside function/method or whatever else, `exit` will do that